# Change output of transformer model to float rather than word

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, transformer-model

My goal is to create a model that can go from a list of tokens (in this case, musical notes) to a list of floats (in this case, the volume of each note). I want the model to be able to look at  the entire sequence of notes, as well as past volumes, in order to determine the volume of the next note. For that reason, it is similar to a machine translation problem, so I used a seq2seq model described here, with some modification:
https://keras.io/examples/nlp/neural_machine_translation_with_transformer/

However, my issue is that this model uses tokens for outputs as well (as seen in the TextEncoder used to encode the output. Right now, I get around that by just rounding the output to a number from 1 to 10, and then tokenizing those numbers. However, this gives bad results because the model cannot tell that these values are on a scale, meaning a 4 instead of a 5 should be acceptable, while a 1 instead of 10 is terrible. Instead, any error is perceived equally thanks to the encoding of the volumes as "words". How can I change the model so the output layer will give a single float (from 0 to 1) rather than a token which is then decoded to such a number, which would then allow me to use some sort of mean error function? In other words, how to change the output from a probability tensor of "which token is the next output" to a single float of the next output.

```py
import pathlib
import random
import string
import re
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
layers = keras.layers
TextVectorization = layers.TextVectorization

data_path = "./language_data/notes_numbers_variation.txt"

with open(data_path) as f:
    lines = f.read().split("\n")[:-1]
text_pairs = []
for line in lines:
    notes, vols = line.split("\t")
    vols = "[start] " + vols + " [end]"
    text_pairs.append((notes, vols))

random.shuffle(text_pairs)
num_val_samples = int(0.15 * len(text_pairs))
num_train_samples = len(text_pairs) - 2 * num_val_samples
train_pairs = text_pairs[:num_train_samples]
val_pairs = text_pairs[num_train_samples : num_train_samples + num_val_samples]
test_pairs = text_pairs[num_train_samples + num_val_samples :]

print(f"{len(text_pairs)} total pairs")
print(f"{len(train_pairs)} training pairs")
print(f"{len(val_pairs)} validation pairs")
print(f"{len(test_pairs)} test pairs")

strip_chars = string.punctuation + "¿"
strip_chars = strip_chars.replace("[", "")
strip_chars = strip_chars.replace("]", "")

vocab_size_notes = 62
vocab_size_vols = 15
sequence_length = 20
batch_size = 64


def custom_standardization(input_string):
    lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_string)
    return tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, "[%s]" % re.escape(strip_chars), "")


notes_vectorization = TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=vocab_size_notes, output_mode="int", output_sequence_length=sequence_length,
)
vols_vectorization = TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=vocab_size_vols,
    output_mode="int",
    output_sequence_length=sequence_length + 1,
    standardize=custom_standardization,
)
train_notes_texts = [pair[0] for pair in train_pairs]
train_vols_texts = [pair[1] for pair in train_pairs]
notes_vectorization.adapt(train_notes_texts)
vols_vectorization.adapt(train_vols_texts)

def format_dataset(notes, vols):
    print("---- ABC1111     " + str(vols))

    notes = notes_vectorization(notes)
    vols = vols_vectorization(vols)
    print("--------- DEF    " + str(vols))
    print("--------- ABC    " + str(vols[:, :-1]))
    return ({"encoder_inputs": notes, "decoder_inputs": vols[:, :-1],}, vols[:, 1:])


def make_dataset(pairs):
    notes_texts, vols_texts = zip(*pairs)
    notes_texts = list(notes_texts)
    vols_texts = list(vols_texts)
    print (vols_texts[1])
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((notes_texts, vols_texts))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.map(format_dataset)
    return dataset.shuffle(2048).prefetch(16).cache()


train_ds = make_dataset(train_pairs)
#print(train_ds[:10])
val_ds = make_dataset(val_pairs)

for inputs, targets in train_ds.take(1):
    print(f'inputs["encoder_inputs"].shape: {inputs["encoder_inputs"].shape}')
    print(f'inputs["decoder_inputs"].shape: {inputs["decoder_inputs"].shape}')
    print(f"targets.shape: {targets.shape}")

class TransformerEncoder(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, dense_dim, num_heads, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.dense_dim = dense_dim
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.attention = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim
        )
        self.dense_proj = keras.Sequential(
            [layers.Dense(dense_dim, activation="relu"), layers.Dense(embed_dim),]
        )
        self.layernorm_1 = layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.layernorm_2 = layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.supports_masking = True

    def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
        print(f"Inputs: {inputs}")
        if mask is not None:
            padding_mask = tf.cast(mask[:, tf.newaxis, :], dtype="int32")
        attention_output = self.attention(
            query=inputs, value=inputs, key=inputs, attention_mask=padding_mask
        )
        proj_input = self.layernorm_1(inputs + attention_output)
        proj_output = self.dense_proj(proj_input)
        return self.layernorm_2(proj_input + proj_output)


class PositionalEmbedding(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, sequence_length, vocab_size, embed_dim, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.token_embeddings = layers.Embedding(
            input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embed_dim
        )
        self.position_embeddings = layers.Embedding(
            input_dim=sequence_length, output_dim=embed_dim
        )
        self.sequence_length = sequence_length
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim

    def call(self, inputs):
        length = tf.shape(inputs)[-1]
        positions = tf.range(start=0, limit=length, delta=1)
        embedded_tokens = self.token_embeddings(inputs)
        embedded_positions = self.position_embeddings(positions)
        return embedded_tokens + embedded_positions

    def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
        return tf.math.not_equal(inputs, 0)


class TransformerDecoder(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, latent_dim, num_heads, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.attention_1 = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim
        )
        self.attention_2 = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim
        )
        self.dense_proj = keras.Sequential(
            [layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation="relu"), layers.Dense(embed_dim),]
        )
        self.layernorm_1 = layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.layernorm_2 = layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.layernorm_3 = layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.supports_masking = True

    def call(self, inputs, encoder_outputs, mask=None):
        causal_mask = self.get_causal_attention_mask(inputs)
        if mask is not None:
            padding_mask = tf.cast(mask[:, tf.newaxis, :], dtype="int32")
            padding_mask = tf.minimum(padding_mask, causal_mask)

        attention_output_1 = self.attention_1(
            query=inputs, value=inputs, key=inputs, attention_mask=causal_mask
        )
        out_1 = self.layernorm_1(inputs + attention_output_1)

        attention_output_2 = self.attention_2(
            query=out_1,
            value=encoder_outputs,
            key=encoder_outputs,
            attention_mask=padding_mask,
        )
        out_2 = self.layernorm_2(out_1 + attention_output_2)

        proj_output = self.dense_proj(out_2)
        return self.layernorm_3(out_2 + proj_output)

    def get_causal_attention_mask(self, inputs):
        input_shape = tf.shape(inputs)
        batch_size, sequence_length = input_shape[0], input_shape[1]
        i = tf.range(sequence_length)[:, tf.newaxis]
        j = tf.range(sequence_length)
        mask = tf.cast(i >= j, dtype="int32")
        mask = tf.reshape(mask, (1, input_shape[1], input_shape[1]))
        mult = tf.concat(
            [tf.expand_dims(batch_size, -1), tf.constant([1, 1], dtype=tf.int32)],
            axis=0,
        )
        return tf.tile(mask, mult)

embed_dim = 64
latent_dim = 512
num_heads = 8

encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int64", name="encoder_inputs")
x = PositionalEmbedding(sequence_length, vocab_size_notes, embed_dim)(encoder_inputs)
encoder_outputs = TransformerEncoder(embed_dim, latent_dim, num_heads)(x)
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_outputs)

decoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int64", name="decoder_inputs")
encoded_seq_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None, embed_dim), name="decoder_state_inputs")
x = PositionalEmbedding(sequence_length, vocab_size_vols, embed_dim)(decoder_inputs)
x = TransformerDecoder(embed_dim, latent_dim, num_heads)(x, encoded_seq_inputs)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
decoder_outputs = layers.Dense(vocab_size_vols, activation="softmax")(x)
decoder = keras.Model([decoder_inputs, encoded_seq_inputs], decoder_outputs)
decoder_outputs = decoder([decoder_inputs, encoder_outputs])



vols_vocab = vols_vectorization.get_vocabulary()
vols_index_lookup = dict(zip(range(len(vols_vocab)), vols_vocab))
max_decoded_sentence_length = 20


def decode_sequence(input_sentence):
    tokenized_input_sentence = notes_vectorization([input_sentence])
    decoded_sentence = "[start]"
    for i in range(max_decoded_sentence_length):
        tokenized_target_sentence = vols_vectorization([decoded_sentence])[:, :-1]
        predictions = transformer([tokenized_input_sentence, tokenized_target_sentence])
        print(predictions)

        sampled_token_index = np.argmax(predictions[0, i, :])
        sampled_token = vols_index_lookup[sampled_token_index]
        decoded_sentence += " " + sampled_token

        if sampled_token == "[end]":
            break
    return decoded_sentence


train = True

if train:

    transformer = keras.Model(
        [encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs, name="transformer"
    )

    epochs = 5  # Converged pretty well with this # on the auto-generated data

    transformer.summary()
    transformer.compile(
        "rmsprop", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]
    )

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs}")
        transformer.fit(train_ds, epochs=1, validation_data=val_ds)
        transformer.save_weights("new_s2s_variation_weights/weights")
        test_notes_texts = [pair[0] for pair in test_pairs]
        print("Example sentences:")
        for _ in range(10):
            input_sentence = random.choice(test_notes_texts)
            translated = decode_sequence(input_sentence)
            print(f"IN: {input_sentence}    OUT: {translated}")



transformer = transformer = keras.Model(
    [encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs, name="transformer"
)
transformer.load_weights("new_s2s_weights/weights")



test_notes_texts = [pair[0] for pair in test_pairs]
for _ in range(1):
    input_sentence = random.choice(test_notes_texts)
    translated = decode_sequence(input_sentence)
    print(f"IN: {input_sentence}    OUT: {translated}")
```